# Running Python on Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I am trying to run a very simple python script via hive and hadoop.

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    nums = line.split()
    i = nums[0]
    print i
```

And I want to run it on the following table:

```
hive> select * from test;
OK
1       3
2       2
3       1
Time taken: 0.071 seconds
hive> desc test;
OK
col1    int
col2    string
Time taken: 0.215 seconds
```

I am running:

```
hive> select transform (col1, col2) using './proba.py' from test;
```

But always get something like:

```
...
2011-11-18 12:23:32,646 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2011-11-18 12:23:58,792 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201110270917_20215 with errors
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

I have tried many different modifications of this procedure but I constantly fail. :(

Am I do something wrong or there is a problem with my hive/hadoop installation?

Comment: Actually, I quited the job and am now working elsewhere with a proper Hadoop setup! ;)

Answer (score 4):

A few things I'd check for if I were debugging this:

**1)** Is the python file set to be executable (chmod +x file.py)

**2)** Make sure the python file is in the same place on all machines. Probably better - put the file in hdfs then you can use " using 'hdfs://path/to/file.py' " instead of a local path

**3)** Take a look at your job on the hadoop dashboard (http://master-node:9100), if you click on a failed task it will give you the actual java error and stack trace so you can see what actually went wrong with the execution

**4)** make sure python is installed on all the slave nodes! (I always overlook this one)

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check hive.log and/or the log from the hadoop job (job_201110270917_20215 in your example)  for a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

"FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask" is a generic error that hive returns when something goes wong in the underlying map/reduce task. You need to go to hive log files(located on the HiveServer2 machine) and find the actual exception stack trace.

Comment: In case of cloudera installation hive log files are at /var/log/hive/hadoop-cmf-HIVE-1-HIVESERVER2-*.out